# Autocomplete constructor calls in IntelliJ/ AndroidStudio

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, android-studio

I'd like to change the code completion for constructors in Android Studio. I'm looking for a Eclipse-like behaviour, For example:

Given the class

```
class Foo{
   public Foo(Object name,Object description, Object address, Object zipCode){ 
       ....
   }
}
```

When, in the code I type `new Foo(` and pres <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> I get a floating hint for the completion but I'd like the IDE to automatically enter the placeholder name for all the params and then I replace the params I need.

Also tried to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Swift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> but it requires to have the field previously declared in the class

Basically I want to speed up to write code like that

```
class MockitoTest {

    Foo foo;

    @Mock
    Object mockName;
    @Mock
    Object mockDescription;
    @Mock
    Object mockAddress;
    @Mock
    Object mockZipCode;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
       foo= new Foo(mockName,mockDescription,mockAddress,mockZipCode);
    }    
}
```

Where the first step is to declare

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
       foo= new Foo(mockName,mockDescription,mockAddress,mockZipCode);
    }
```

And then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and select the option `Create field for mockName` for each param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version 1.1, Android Studio does not support this behavior.